# How to get all tables from SQLite database Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been searching on how to get all tables from a database, I'm not familiar with SQLite for Android Studio. I have a DBHelper class that I use to make my sql commands. What I've gathered so far is that I have to make a query to sqlite_master such as "**SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'**".

Here is my DBHelper class:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public String tableName;
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
private static final String COLUMN_DESC = "desc";
private static final String COLUMN_DECKNAME = "deckname";
private static final String COLUMN_IMAGENAME = "imagename";

public DBHelper(Context context, String tablename) {
    super(context, "UserDecks.db", null, 1);
    tableName = tablename;
}

public DBHelper(Context context){
    super(context, "UserDecks.db", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "(" + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_DESC + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_DECKNAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_IMAGENAME + " TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName);
}

@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + "(" + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_DESC + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_DECKNAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_IMAGENAME + " TEXT)");
}

public Cursor GetDeckList(){
    SQLiteDatabase sdb = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
    return cursor;
}
```

I only pasted where it reaches up to the GetDeckList method.

This is where I reference DBHelper:

```
    db = new DBHelper(this);
    Cursor cData = db.GetDeckList();
    int numOfRows = cData.getCount();
    if(numOfRows == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Deck list is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        while(cData.moveToNext()){
            DL_deckList = new DeckList(cData.getString(0));
            LIST_currentDecks.add(DL_deckList);
        }
        mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(true, LIST_currentDecks, this);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    }
```

I think I am missing some piece of code, because I'm doing what I've read on stackoverflow on how to query from sqlite_master, but my app keeps crashing because I keep trying to create a "null" table. It keeps calling "**onCreate**" or "**onOpen**" when I tinker with the code, even though I'm not trying to make a table. So it keeps crashing because I'm not giving it a new table. So I'm assuming I'm missing some code, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
db = new DBHelper(this);
Cursor cData = db.GetDeckList();
if(cData != null) {
    int numOfRows = cData.getCount();
    if(numOfRows == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Deck list is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
    
        List<String> tableNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        cData.moveToFirst();
        while (!cData.isAfterLast()) {
            tableNames.add(cData.getString(cData.getColumnIndex("name")));
            cData.moveToNext();
        }
        mAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(true, tableNames, this);
        
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the code from `onCreate`, `onUpgrade`, `onOpen` and that will give you the results you are looking for.

The result from `GetDeckList` would be only one record: `android_metadata`, a table by default.

If you need to create tables in the future, then add the code back to `onCreate`, in that case, you could have some constants in your `DBHandler` for your new tables.

Finally, I recommend you have a Singleton to have only one instance of `DBHandler` to avoid memory leaks or memory allocations. Another piece of advice would be If you can use the abstraction library `Room` from the Android Jetpack, much better, this library will save you from important issues from using SQLite directly. If you want to check Room out, please check [Room Setup](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following query for get all database tables

```
 //use below query for reading all table list
   Cursor cursor = sdb.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name NOT IN ('android_metadata', 'sqlite_sequence', 'room_master_table') ",null);
```